# iOS Swype Keyboard Uncaught Exception Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Recently I encountered and issue in iOS that force closes the app when tapping on a text box. First, I thought it was something to do with Ionic View, so I built the app using Xcode. Still had the same issue. I started digging through the device console and noticed that I received an uncaught exception from the app when the keyboard is switching. Something about the keyboard UI was using a background thread, but any UI needed to be on the main thread. I was using the Swype keyboard at the time, so I turned Swype off and used the stock iOS keyboard. So far I have not had any issues using the stock keyboard.

Has anyone had any issue with using third party keyboards with iOS? This is a show stopper for my app at this point for iOS. I haven't had any issue with Android.

Comment: It would help to have more details about the exception. Turn on exception breakpoints in Xcode if you don't already and run the app. It should give you a clue where the exception is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with swype keyboard and webview input fields on iOS 9.
The only solution right now is to restrict the use of 3rd party keyboards on your input fields.
You can use this plugin to do so

https://github.com/kurtisf/cordova-plugin-restrict-keyboard

just install it with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/kurtisf/cordova-plugin-restrict-keyboard
```

no code needed

Comment: I am new to iOS building, the app still crashes when I load in with Ionic View on the iPhone. Would I need to build it in xCode for it to work?

Comment: yes, it will only fix the issue on your own app, ionic view developers will have to fix it on their app.

Comment: Just completed testing and the app is functioning correctly. Thank @jcesarmobile

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your keyboard library instance in singleton class and then use the same reference everywhere in the app.This thing fixed my crash and i hope it will help you as well.

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to provide an example, this type of development is still fairly new to me.

Comment: @BrandonWilson please write your code or let me know what library you are using so that i can give you sample code